# Wrong string parsing from remote service

Tags: java, string, parsing

An arbitrary string comes from the remote service.

Depending on the presence of the `Body:` substring, I must parse it in various ways, I do this:

```
    String longString = service.getString();

    if (longString.indexOf("Body:") != -1) {
        // some code
    } else {
        // enother code
    }
```

But when the string comes in and looks like `Body:\Dsdqwe ....` logic runs from the`else` block. How can I fix it?

Comment: add a print statement right before your if, to print longString. this should not go to the else block if the String is "Body:\..."

Comment: It's a very long `String` but I need only focus on `Body:` substring. Maybe `\D`could create the problem?. It prints `Body:\Dsdqwe...` in `else` block

Comment: normally not. the index should be 0 and not -1

Comment: Could it be that the `\D` character can remove the previous character or spoil the previous line?

Comment: no. escape characters escape the character after them. it doesn't (shouldn't) impact what comes before them

Comment: but: "Body:\Dsdqwe" is an illegal String, it should be: "Body:\\Dsdqwe"

Comment: did you try to put the print statement?

Comment: It prints whole String in else statment `Body:\Dsdqwe....`

Comment: try with the replaceAll("\","\\") (or to ""), it might help

Comment: The escape character is not important, if the input string is not from within the Java Program. You can perfectly read 'asdf\Dasdf' from a text file and process the string from it.

Comment: I made a file with content as **Body:\Dsdqwe** and read that file to initialize **longString**, rest of the code is same. For me the if block is executing

Comment: @DenisVabishchevich are you sure you are running the latest version of your code? did you save/recompile/build after your last updates? seems stupid, but it happens ...

Comment: My method works on all other examples with a substring containing `Body:`, but this example breaks. Thanks to everyone, maybe a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: @DenisVabishchevich If your code works fine but for one specific input, the reason is clearly this input. Is that problematic input bigger than the others? Is that problematic input the only one containing an escape sequence? What are the specific differences between the problematic input and all others? There must be something special.

Comment: @DenisVabishchevich Maybe stupid, but are you sure that your `Body:` fragment in the `longString` contains all latin characters and no others, cyrillic "o" for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead -

String longString = service.getString();

```
if (longString.contains("Body:")) {
    // some code
} else {
    // enother code
}
```

Comment: `String.contains` is using `String.indexOf` under the hood

Comment: @DenisVabishchevich it won't fix your issue, but Rishikesh has a point. after all, you don't care what place in the String it is found, you just are verifying that "Body:" is in your String, making contains(String param) a possible better fit

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one I think,

```
String longString = service.getString().replaceAll("\","");
if (longString.indexOf("Body:") != -1) {
        // some code
    } else {
        // enother code
    }
```

Comment: do you mean "replaceAll"?

Comment: Maybe better to `longString.replaceAll("\","\\");` but it could make a perfomance problems on `longString`

Comment: @DenisVabishchevich true, but if you would try to do: String test = "Body:\D"; it wouldn't compile, so chance is, the '\' is messing it up. I would expect another error message, though, but still

Answer (score 0):

This is an interessting issue.

I created the following text file named ´strings.txt´:

```
Hallo Welt
Body:
Body:Content
Body:\Dasdf
```

And a little method that reads each string and tests it against your check:

```
public void foobar()
{
    // As the character \D is an invalid escape sequence, you can not hard code it without using double \.
    // But using double \ would change the actual input as in the process, so read the data from a file.
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("strings.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringList.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // All strings are read from the file, now process and test each one of them
    for(String str : stringList ) {

        if (str.indexOf("Body:") != -1) {
            System.out.println("'" + str + "' - Is containing the search term");
        } else {
            System.out.println("'" + str + "' - Is _NOT_ containing the search term");
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the output I get, when running the above:

```
'Hallo Welt' - Is _NOT_ containing the search term
'Body:' - Is containing the search term
'Body:Content' - Is containing the search term
'Body:\Dasdf' - Is containing the search term
```

Conclusion:
If your program receives a string like `Body:\Dasdf`, it can be processed correctly and without any problems. The source of the issue must lay somewhere else.

The following are just a few ideas, where the problem might come from:

- Encoding: The source is sending the string in another encoding than the receiving machine. Therefore the receiver mixes up the characters and the string comparison fails.
- Compilation: Maybe your source code has not been compiled due to errors in the code or misconfiguration in your IDE

Steps you can do, to verify a few things:

- Check if your code has really been compiled
- Are you using serialisation? If yes, check possible encoding issues.
- About encoding: Don't trust your IDE, it might convert stuff for you. Write out the original received string into a simple text file and open that file with a text editor like Notepad or Notepad++ to check the encoding.

Comment: quite extensive, but in a sense this post is a comment, not an answer

Comment: This post is way to long for a comment, also the code formatting in a comment is not that nice.